# When using transform: scale() is it possible to keep paddings?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a slider to display images. I want to have the selected image (which is always the img in the middle) to be scaled bigger as the others. When I use `transform: scale(1.1);` it works how it supposed to do.

The problem I'm having is that the `scale()` property overflows the padding of my image. I want the same gap length between all images. Is this possible in any way? Hope I made it understandable.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPvgGX

[image: before scale()][image: after scale()]

Comment: One way is you can try margin instead of padding along with the scale. Please provide JS Fidle link to your code, so that it will be easier to rectify your problem.

Comment: increase the padding while scaling

Comment: i added a codepen example

Comment: @TemaniAfif when I increase the padding it breaks the scaling

Comment: @JoykalInfotech using margin instead doesn't work either ...

Comment: These items are not _actually_ kept apart by any margins; the slider script positions them all absolutely and calculates the necessary left coordinate. And it does that based on the actual width of the items (which scaling doesn’t change.) So you would probably have to dig quite deep into the script to find a point where you could start and rectify that. If you need this on a solid background only, then probably a border around the current item could give you a similar(!) effect, by overlapping the images to the left and right a bit.

Comment: The other option could be to change the actual width of the element, and then call the resize method to have the slider update itself accordingly. https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#resize

Comment: A `transform` is **purely** visual and **does not affect actual layout or element sizes**

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah I thought there might be a hacky workaround :)

Comment: @misorude thanks for that hint! I'm playing around with that right now